# LovyanGFX library not working anymore (ESP-32)

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, lcd, gfx

I am trying to restore an old project and make a code that used to run compile again.
However, I am always getting this error, which is from the **LovyanGFX** graphics library:

```
Compilation error: 'LGFX_SPI' in namespace 'lgfx' does not name a template type
```

The line causing the error is this: `static LGFX lcd;`

This problem also occurs with all included examples of the library without me modifying anything.

Any help appreciated!